# Ubuntu 16.04 server не устанавливается

Tags: ubuntu, сервер

Какая то беда с установкой 16 версии ubuntu. В процессе установки после просмотра компакт диска она перестаёт что то делать. Просто останавливается и при этом реагирует на ввод с клавиатуры. В чём может быть беда? Дебиан сусе цент убунту 14 - все ставились нормально на данное железо.

[image: экран после остановки]

Comment: Возможно, битый диск.

Comment: Подождите минут пять-десять.

Comment: Серверную редакцию пробовал поставить?

Comment: Битый диск по ходу, попробуйте на виратуальной машине.

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev спасибо. Постояла машина ночь - установка пошла дальше). Всё норм после этого.